# Prevent first form submit when submit second from

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, laravel-5

Here is the deal (using php and laravel-5.2).
I have some `forms` in a page, and when i submit `another form` not the first one then it keeps submit the `first form`.
Here my html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/candidates/18" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="name-edit" style="display:none">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
     <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xxzvu6HIqP8k2kg78pxuHiTc8NWftjNL1IJvxbDo">
     <div  class="form-group ">
         <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
             <input placeholder="Full Name" error="" id="name-input" class="width-100" name="name" type="text" value="chi qua uqaaa1232">
         </div>
     </div>
     <button class="green btn-link col-xs-4" type="submit"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Click to save or press Enter</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/candidates/18" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="address-edit" style="display:none">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
     <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xxzvu6HIqP8k2kg78pxuHiTc8NWftjNL1IJvxbDo">
     <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
               <input placeholder="Address" error="" id="address-input" class="width-100" name="address" type="text" value="nha xacdawdwad">
          </div>
     </div>
     <button class="green btn-link col-xs-4" type="submit"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Click to save or press Enter</button>
</form>
```

My jquery code for both forms:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name-edit").focusout(function() {
        $('#name-edit').css('display', 'none');
        $('#name-view').css('display', 'inline');
    });

    $("#address-edit").focusout(function() {
        $('#address-edit').css('display', 'none');
        $('#address-view').css('display', 'inline');
    });
});

$('#btn-edit-name').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name-view').css('display', 'none').clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $('#name-input').val(name);
    $('#name-edit').css('display', 'inline').focus();
});

$('#btn-edit-address').click(function () {
    var name = $('#address-view').css('display', 'none').clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $('#address-input').val(name);
    $('#address-edit').css('display', 'inline').focus();
});
```

`btn-edit-name` and `btn-edit-address` for showing the form. thanks for your consider.
here is my UI:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i found the answer that set the `type` submit button to `button` then make `jquery` for click event `$(this).closest('form').submit()`

Answer (score 1):

> You can't submit 2 forms simultaneously.

Instead of having 2 forms for name and address fields you can add them into single form like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/candidates/18" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="name-edit" style="display:none">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
     <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xxzvu6HIqP8k2kg78pxuHiTc8NWftjNL1IJvxbDo">
     <div  class="form-group ">
         <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
             <input placeholder="Full Name" error="" id="name-input" class="width-100" name="name" type="text" value="chi qua uqaaa1232">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
           <input placeholder="Address" error="" id="address-input" class="width-100" name="address" type="text" value="nha xacdawdwad">
        </div>
     </div>
     <button class="green btn-link col-xs-4" type="submit"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Click to save or press Enter</button>
</form>
```

If you wish to show hide them on click then you can add some jQuery to do so.

Comment: i dont want to submit simultaneously 2 forms. I just want to submit only 1 form for each submition, thanks for other solution

Answer (score 0):

You can either have two different actions

```
action="http://localhost:8888/candidates/18"

action="http://localhost:8888/candidates/19"
```

If not possible add different hidden input to each form like

In form 1 add this line

```
 <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="form1">
```

In form 2 add this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="form2">
```

Now you can either use `if ($_POST['identifier'] == 'form1')`

OR

You can use a switch statement also

```
switch($_POST['identifier']){
    case 'form1':{}
    case 'form2':{}
}
```

Also your two submit buttons are identical. You can set a value for each that you can check after submission. Set value like this
For form 1 name

```
<button class="green btn-link col-xs-4" type="submit" value="name" name="name"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Click to save or press Enter</button>
```

For form 2 address

```
<button class="green btn-link col-xs-4" type="submit" value="address" name="address"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Click to save or press Enter</button>
```

Comment: when i `vardump` the request only has data form first form, both form must submit to same place

Comment: @HọTên at a time only one form can be submitted that is how the request/response model works

Comment: i dont want submit 2 form at the same time

Comment: @HọTên Give different values and names to your submit button and then check.